# Switching to MariaDB with Zend Framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, mariadb

I've been developing a site on

```
MySQL client version: 5.1.41
Server version: 5.1.41
```

And I've been considering the deployment onto the production server could be the best time to migrate to maria db (Ubuntu Lucid Lynx)

What settings do I need to change in my application config

```
resources.multidb.front_db.adapter  = "pdo_mysql"
resources.multidb.front_db.charset  = "utf8"
resources.multidb.front_db.host     = localhost
resources.multidb.front_db.username = root
resources.multidb.front_db.password = ****
resources.multidb.front_db.dbname   = ****
resources.multidb.front_db.default  = true
```

Would I just need to replace pdo_mysql with pdo_mariadb? (is there such an adapter?)

Can I create the dump of my database(mainly innoDB,a few MyISAM and a some views) in mysql and import then import it into mariadb?

Anything else I should lookout for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MariaDB is a binary drop in replacement for MySQL** ([source](http://kb.askmonty.org/v/mariadb-versus-mysql-compatibility))

There is no pdo adapter for mariadb, you use pdo_mysql and as far as PHP knows, that's what it is.

As far as data conversion goes, I would probably just use mysqldump (or phpMyAdmin) to move the data, and manually convert which ever tables you want to convert by hand to mariadb's alternate storage engine(s).

Good luck! I haven't had the opportunity to use mariadb in production, but I'm dying for an excuse to.

Comment: Right, it seems like you use the adapter string `'pdo_mysql'` or `'mysqli'` and PHP is none the wiser.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with 0 problem. installed it with apt get, installation went almost identical to mysql. Installed php my admin and everything behaved normal. Deployed my application and all is working

Comment: out of curiosity, what apt repos are you using? I really wish mariadb would make it in some more "official" repositories so it would get a little more exposure by lazy folks like me.

Comment: I used this short tutorial here http://posidev.com/blog/2010/10/05/install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx/